# Find all possible Jordan forms of a complex matrix with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, jordan-normal-form

**Q:** Given a matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
a & b+c \\ 
b-c & -a 
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$. Find all possible Jordan forms.

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps start by determining the characteristic polynomial. What kind of eigenvalues are possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy calculation shows that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
\begin{equation}
X^2-a^2-b^2+c^2.
\end{equation}

If $a^2+b^2-c^2\ne0$ then the eigenvalues $\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}$ are distinct. Hence $A$ is diagonalizable and all possible Jordan forms are
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}&0\\0&\mp\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Now assume $a^2+b^2-c^2=0$. Then $A$ has only one eigenvalue $0$. Moreover $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A=0$, i.e., $a=b=c=0$. Hence all possible Jordan forms of $A$ are
\begin{align}
&\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix},&&\text{if $a=b=c=0$},\\
&\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{pmatrix},&&\text{otherwise}.
\end{align}